# Select HTML elements by variable substring of a property

Tags: jquery

I have several groups of elements, each group of which is related to a particular number.  I want to add a mouseover to each element that adds a class to all the elements in its group, and a mouseout that removes that class.  jQuery's attributeStartsWith selector works great for this as long as I give it a string literal, but I'm trying to write a function to do this with any group, so I need the selection to take a parameter as the substring.  Is there a way to do this with attributeStartsWith, or should I try some other technique?

Here's what I have that works:

```
function highlight(numberString)
{ $('p[id^="321"]').addClass("highlighted");  }
```

I need to replace "321" with the parameter numberString.  The following doesn't seem to do that.  I gather that's because attributeStartsWith treats numberString as an unquoted single-word string and not a variable name.

```
function highlight(numberString)
{ $('p[id^=numberString]').addClass("highlighted");  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert and quote the argument as a string:

```
function highlight(numberString) {
    $('p[id^=' + numberString + ']').addClass("highlighted");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3qHX/

Javascript doesn't have variable string expansion/interpolation like PHP, by the way. This is obvious if you think about it, but carry-over can still happen, leading to problems (if that's your situation).

Also, the value you're testing for in the selector does not need to be quoted unless it has a space, so the following is probably not needed but does not *hurt*:

```
function highlight(numberString) {
    $('p[id^="' + numberString + '"]').addClass("highlighted");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3qHX/1

Note the `"` I've added. `id` values should not have spaces in them anyhow, but if this were used with other attribute selectors, you would need to be careful.

Another note is that the `id` attribute pre-HTML5 required starting with an alphanumeric letter (can't be an alphanumeric number only). HTML5 changed this, but I think (*my preference and recommendation*) is that in most use-cases the previous standard should be followed.

Comment: Ah, that worked perfectly.  I was misreading those innermost single quotes as open-close instead of close-open.  Thanks very much!